# Fragment throwing Nullpointer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

So I have problem manipulating my `TextView` inside `Fragment`.
I have simple callback interface defining only `onCallBackReceived()`, when my method `onCallbackReceived()` is called back I want to change text of my `TextView`, however method `setText("onCallback")` throws `NullPointerException`. Exception says that the method is called on null object reference, but I initialized it first using `findViewById()`. Please help.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MySimpleCallback {

     TextView textView;

     @Nullable
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_fragment, container, false);
     }

     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
         textView.setText("Okay!");
     }

     @Override
     public void onCallbackReceived() {
         textView.setText("onCallback");
     }
```

}

Comment: Can you describe how you are calling `onCallbackReceived()` method?

Comment: `MySimpleCallback mySimpleCallback;` then in on create `mySimpleCallback = new MyFargment();` and calling by `public void call( MySimpleCallback mySimpleCallback) {
       mySimleCallback.onCallbackReceived();
    }`

Comment: is textView.setText("okay") working properly?

Comment: Yes this is surprising ;D

Comment: Can you add the whole code like where you are instantiating your fragment, activity etc?

Comment: Thats a lot of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148925/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-user221256).

Comment: Your textView may not exist when the callback is being called. It would be a better idea to pass the entire textview through the callback if you need it to display 100%. Be careful of possible leaks however.

Comment: What do you mean by passing entire textview?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can findTheViewById in the onCreateView

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MySimpleCallback {

     TextView textView;

     @Nullable
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_fragment, container, false);
         textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
         return view;
     }

     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         textView.setText("Okay!");
     }

     @Override
     public void onCallbackReceived() {
         textView.setText("onCallback");
     }
}
```

Comment: Still the same issue ;(